# What are some alternate ways I can access this php array?

Tags: php, arrays, variable-variables

**DETAILS**

I have a separate problem that I am investigating that seems to be related to the way I am accessing arrays. Hence this possibly odd question.

I have the following array

```
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos0'] ='zero';
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1'] ='one';
```

I would like to use the current **subscription level** to determine the agreetotos name.
For the moment let's assume that `$subscriptionlevel =1;`

That means the value I am trying to retrieve =  `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1'];`

I know I can access this value by using `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'.$subscriptionlevel];`

or I can use variable variables to access the array with the following

```
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'.${'subscriptionlevel'}];
```

**QUESTION**

Are there any other ways?

If yes, what are the advantages/drawbacks of using them?

**EDIT**

I haven't properly explained what I am trying to achieve. I'm looking for syntax equivalent to `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1']`

For example, `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'][1]` is not equal to  `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1']`

whereas

`$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'.$subscriptionlevel]` is the same as `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1']`.

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: There are dozens of other ways.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Please see my edit

Comment: What is **wrong** with the way you know?

Comment: Perhaps nothing. This is just a small part of a bigger problem I'm looking at. So, I'm turning stones and poking sticks at stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do this is..

```
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'][0] ='zero';
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'][1] ='one';
```

And you can access this as..

```
$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'][$subscriptionlevel];
```

Comment: I can see the merit in writing it this way even though it is not quite what I meant. At first, I thought you were saying that `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos'][1]` was the same as `$response['custom_validation']['agreetotos1']`